# Are there any blueprint's function to replace/delete content?

Tags: javascript, ember-cli, blueprint

I have such a task: I want to create blueprint to replace default Resolver with my own custom one in `app/app.js` file. But I've found only `insertIntoFile` function.

So, my question is: is there any default function for replacing/deleting content from file similar to `insertIntoFile` function, or I should implement it?

Comment: I don't think there is a insertIntoFile function, would you be so nice and share a link of your source?

Comment: This is function from `Blueprint.prototype`, you can see it here https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/lib/models/blueprint.js#L936

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I want to give it a shot anyway.

Make a file in `blueprints/<blueprint-name>/files/app/app.js`. Then modify that file to your own needs.